# Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps REST API- Insufficient role based permissions

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft365-defender

I am trying to investigate file uploads to see if they are matched by File Scan policies in Microsoft Defender for Cloud Apps (aka MCAS). I can see them fine at the portal but I need to automate the process via API.

As per documentation, I did create Azure AD application and provided the permissions. This is needed to get access token which is needed to make api calls.
[image: Azure AD App Permissions]

I am getting Insufficient role based permissions error when I call https://aspnet4you2.us3.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/files/.
I get same error if I use https://portal.cloudappsecurity.com/cas/api/v1/files/

Any idea how to solve this Insufficient permission issue?

[image: Calling cloudappsecurity API]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I registered one Azure AD application and granted **API permissions** as below:

[image]

Now I generated **`access token`** via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenantID>/oauth2/v2.0/token

client_id:appID
grant_type:client_credentials
client_secret:secret
scope:05a65629-4c1b-48c1-a78b-804c4abdd4af/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used the above token to get files with both URLs, I got **same error** as below:

```http
GET https://portal.cloudappsecurity.com/cas/api/v1/files/
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

```http
GET https://mytenantname.us3.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/files/
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

With the same token, I'm able to call all **other APIs** like alerts, activities etc. like below:

```http
GET https://mytenantname.us3.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/alerts/
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

[image]

> Note that, calling **`file APIs`** is not available in **application
> context**.

Alternatively, you can make use of **`Legacy Method`** by generating one **API token** like below:

***Go to Defender for Cloud Apps portal -> Settings -> Security extensions -> API tokens -> Add a token***

[image]

Now, enter Token name and select ***Generate*** as below:

[image]

**API token** will be generated successfully and copy the token to use in Postman:

[image]

When I used the above API token to call **`files API`** with both URLs, I got **response** successfully as below:

```http
GET https://portal.cloudappsecurity.com/cas/api/v1/files/
Authorization: Token <token>
```

[image]

```http
GET https://mytenantname.us3.portal.cloudappsecurity.com/api/v1/files/
Authorization: Token <token>
```

[image]

You can try the same in your environment by generating **API token** instead of Bearer token to call Files API.

**Reference:**

[Defender for Cloud Apps file API “Insufficient role based permissions” by ***Sangho Cho***](https://blog.scho.kr/en-us/microsoft365/Defender-for-Cloud-Apps-API-file-permission-error/)

Comment: @Sridevi- Thank you very much for the answer. Appreciate you for going extra miles to replicate the issue and then providing a tested workaround. I followed your instructions to use api key and it worked for me as well. Way to go!